# Transmitting ipv4 packets directly in java

Tags: java, networking, ipv4

Is there a way to connect to a network interface on the computer in Java? That would allow you to design your own ipv4 packet in form of `byte[]`.

I am trying to learn networking from the ground up, and it would help if I could test my own packet design.

I know this might be too much to explain on Stack Overflow, but anything that could get me on the right path is appreciated. Even if you only have a class or a word I could Google.

Comment: Java is unsuitable for low level operations due to the platform independence and other design choices, so if you intend to concentrate on Java, you should try to forget them (at least until you start with JNI/JNA). If you're adamant on wanting to do everything from "ground up", then go with a more suitable language.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for raw sockets, and no, I there is no direct support in Java for it.

There is https://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/, which provides raw sockets in Java.

But maybe you should try Python for this kind of low-level network programming, it is IMHO better suited for your task.